# How to add description to the User Change Page in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django and wanted to add a description under the heading at the red mark in the User change page as shown in the pic

[image: pic]

my admin.py file look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser','is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So what should I do to get a description at the red mark in the user creation page??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a description in the User Change Page the first thing you have to do is add a line to your admin file and that is :

`change_form_template = 'change_form.html'`

So that your entire admin file looks like :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser','is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

After that go to the templates folder and add a html file with name : `change_form.html`

Then add following code in the `change_form.html` :

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}


{% block form_top %}
<p>Add here your description for User Change Page.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

That's all you have to do.